# Prove that $[0,\infty)$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ without connectedness

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, open-map

I want to prove that the metric space $([0,\infty), |\cdot|)$ is not homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ (or $((0,\infty),|\cdot|)$, whichever is easier) without using the notion of connectedness.

I have only been given the definition of a homeomorphism in the question (a continuous bijection between topologies/metric spaces whose inverse is also continuous). I am also allowed to use the following definition of continuity:

$f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open set is open. I.e $U\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X: f(x)\in U\}\subseteq X$ is open.

Part 1 of the question asks us to prove that for homeomorphic spaces, the image of every open set is open. I am not sure if this is helpful. Can someone give some pointers or an outline of a solution?

Comment: I would look around the preimage of $0$ by the homemorphism $\phi:\mathbf{R} \to [0,\infty)$ to show $\phi$ can not be a bijection using the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the intermediate value theorem count as using connectedness?

If $f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, then it is in particular a continuous bijection. By surjectivity, there must be $y,z>0$ such that $f(y) = f(0) - 1$ and $f(z) = f(0) + 1$. Use the intermediate value theorem to deduce that there is some $x>0$ such that $f(x)=f(0)$, contradicting injectivity of $f$.

Comment: No, as it is assumed knowledge from previous years coursework

Comment: Why should $y,z$ necessarily be $>0$??

Comment: @crskhr Because they cannot be $0$.

Comment: they can be less than 0

Comment: @crskhr No element of $[0,\infty)$ is less than $0$.